# PHP Using single fscanf to read from multiple lines?

Tags: php, format, scanf, format-string

According to PHP documentation

> ```
> mixed fscanf ( resource $handle , string $format [, mixed &$... ] )
> ```
>
> Each call to fscanf() reads one line from the file.

Now I am trying to read this output from a file using single fscanf()

These are line separated inputs.

***8***

***4.0***

***is the best place to learn***

using this code

```
fscanf("%d \n %f \n %[^\\n]");
```

but the output I am getting is

***8***

***blank***

***blank***

What is the correct code for it to read using single fscanf?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to read multiple lines from a file with a single fscanf. An alternative is to call fscanf multiple times, one for each line. An alternative which will read all the lines in one go is the file() function.

Comment: I doubt you will notice any speed difference between them.

Comment: But functionally which is more efficient.

Comment: It's hard to say without trying it. I doubt that there is any noticeable difference between them in terms of performance. I would choose whichever makes the code simpler.